# Javascript Remoting salesforce unknown property remote action

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting, custom-controller, remote-action

**My VisualForce page:**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="JavascriptRemotingController" showHeader="false">

<head>
</head>

<body id="bd">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AccountName() {
            var fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}', fname, function (result, event) {

                if (event.status) {
                    document.getElementById("{!$Component.bd.div.firstname}").innerHTML = result;
                }
                else if (result.type === 'exception') {
                    alert("Exception caught");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Exception caught");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div id="div">
        First Name :
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstname"> </input>
        <br></br>
        <button onclick="AccountName()">Submit</button>

    </div>
</body>
```

</apex:page>

**My Apex controller:**

```
global with sharing class JavascriptRemotingController {
public static void JavascriptRemotingController()
{
    
}
@RemoteAction
global Static Account AccountName(String fname)
{
    System.debug('getAccount');
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.name = fname;
    try {
        insert acc;
        return acc;
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        System.debug('Error: ' +exp);
        return null ; 
        
    }

}
```

}

*I want to create an account record when a client enters the name in the input field.*

Answer (score 3):

You need to use $RemoteAction, not RemoteAction, and the class name and method name must match:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  '{!$RemoteAction.JavascriptRemotingController.AccountName}', 
  fname, 
  function (result, event) {
     // ... rest of code ...
```

I realize you may be trying to learn how to use remoting, but a better solution to this particular problem would be [Visualforce Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects.htm), which is better suited for creating, updating, querying, and deleting records.

Comment: Thank you for your input.

Comment: result is null.

Comment: @HarshitSaxena Presumably, you're getting an error, then. Consider fixing your Apex code to not use try-catch.